# Calling F# Library with Akka.Net actors from C# library leads to TypeInitializationException

Tags: c#, f#, .net-4.5, akka.net

I have in my test solution 3 projects:

- f# class library (let's name it F#Lib),
- f# console application (let's name it F#Console) and
- c# console application (C#Console).

In the class library I define an akka.net actor:

```
namespace Just.Test.Project

open Akka.Actor
open Akka.FSharp
open Akka.Configuration

module Actors =

    let system = System.create "WaveNetSystem" (Configuration.defaultConfig())

    let simple = spawn system "simple" (fun mailbox ->
        let rec loop() = actor {
            let! message = mailbox.Receive()
            printfn "%A" message
            return! loop()
        }
        loop()
    )

type MainClass(msg) = let x = Actors.simple <! msg
```

If I instantiate the `MainClass` from f# console application, I get expected result:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    Just.Test.Project.MainClass("bugaga!") |> ignore
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

output:

```
"bugaga!!!"
```

But. If I do the same from c# console app:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    new Just.Test.Project.MainClass("bugaga!");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

I get an exception:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for '<StartupCode$SampleFSharpAkkaNet>.$Test' threw an exception. ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Akka.Actor.IActorRef  Akka.FSharp.Spawn.spawn(Akka.Actor.IActorRefFactory, System.String, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<Actor`1<!!0>,Cont`2<!!0,!!1>>)'.
   at <StartupCode$SampleFSharpAkkaNet>.$Test..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Just.Test.Project.Actors.get_simple()
   at Just.Test.Project.MainClass..ctor() in d:\prj\research\AkkaFSharpTest\SampleFSharpAkkaNet\Test.fs:line 20
```

How should I interpret this exception? What might be wrong?

**UPDATE**

As already noted in comments and in Tomas Petricek answer, the issue is related to the version mismatch. The `bindingRedirect` does the job and everything starts working. But I still have some misunderstanding.

First. The `Akka.FSharp` references `FSharp.Core 4.3.1`.

Second. The F#Lib and F#Console references `FSharp.Core 4.4.0` and C#Console has no references to `FSharp.Core` at all.

Third. The F#Console works like a charm and if I print loaded assemblies I get:

```
FSharpConsole, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
FSharpLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

FSharp.Core, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a

Akka, Version=1.0.6.16, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
Akka.FSharp, Version=1.0.6.16, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

FsPickler, Version=1.2.21.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
System.Numerics, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

so, no `FSharp.Core 4.3.1.0` loaded and everything is tip-top!

Fourth. The C#Console does not work. The list of loaded assemblies looks a bit strange:

```
CSharpConsole, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
FSharpLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

FSharp.Core, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
FSharp.Core, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a

Akka, Version=1.0.6.16, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
Akka.FSharp, Version=1.0.6.16, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

It means both `FSharp.Core, Version=4.4.0.0` and `FSharp.Core, Version=4.3.1.0` are loaded. Why? And why it does not happened in F#Console case?

**SOLUTION**

The problem (as usually )) was in my head.

First of all, I never looked into the final F#Console config. The initial `app.config` is quite simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

but after the build it gets (thanks to [AutoGenerateBindingRedirects MSBuild flag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2(v=vs.110).aspx)) the required buinding redirects:

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.4.0.0" newVersion="4.4.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

The second one. C# compiler was trying to notify me about the problem by writing such messages in the build output:

> No way to resolve conflict between "FSharp.Core, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "FSharp.Core, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "FSharp.Core, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
>   Consider app.config remapping of assembly "FSharp.Core, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "4.3.1.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp.NETFramework\v4.0\4.3.1.0\FSharp.Core.dll] to Version "4.4.0.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp.NETFramework\v4.0\4.4.0.0\FSharp.Core.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): warning MSB3276: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. Please set the "AutoGenerateBindingRedirects" property to true in the project file. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=294190.

But I decided that C# compiler is just a little more restrictive as F# compiler. I didn't know that in F# projects the flag is set automatically. What stoped me from checking it? I do not know! )

Comment: You have different versions of some libraries referenced in different projects.

Comment: Exceptions says that `spawn` method hasn't been recognized in C# app. Do you have Akka.FSharp and FSharp.Core assemblies referenced in your C# project?

Comment: @horusiath It is what I also thought, but no, everything looks correct here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like an `FSharp.Core.dll` version mismatch issue.

Most likely, you are referencing a newer version of `FSharp.Core.dll` than the one that has been referenced by the F# wrapper library for Akka.net. You can either reference the same version, or add a config file with `bindingRedirect`. See [Mark Seemann's blog post](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/01/30/how-to-use-fsharpcore-430-when-all-you-have-is-431/).

The keyword here is `MethodMissingException` - you are getting that because the signature of the method involves types from `FSharp.Core.dll` and the version that has been loaded (based on the reference in the C# project) does not match the version exposed by the wrapper (based on the reference used when compiling the wrapper). Because of the version mismatch, the types are treated as different and "method is not found".

Comment: You are right, the `bindingRedirect` helps a lot. But still have no idea, why it differs from F# version. I've updated my post, could you please have a look?

Comment: Doesn't the F# project automatically generate the config file with binding redirects? I think there is some MSBuild option to do that...

Comment: Ahhh,,,,, It really does! I wasn't aware of MSBuild option and never looked in the final config. In the initial app.config of course were no binding redirects.